# Notification not display when app in foreground using Firebase

Tags: android

I am using firebase push notification which come from server but when app in foreground the notification not display pls help me out

Comment: In background notification builder is handled and displayed by firebase sdk but in foreground you have to do it in you code.

Comment: can you suggest me how to do it in code ?

Comment: are you using  type "Notification message" or "Data message" https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options ?

Comment: @NamrataRajgor check my answer.

Comment: Hi i am using "Data message" type for notification.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [offcial link](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/java/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java) for complete reference.

If you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM do something like this

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.

       sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());// or pass value fetched from data payload
...
}
```

Then delcare Notification builder like this,

```
 private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
                        .setContentText(messageBody)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Since android Oreo notification channel is needed.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for suggestion.the issue has been resolved.now i got the notification in foreground.